# SwiftyJson array in array

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I parse JSON from server with Alamofire and SwiftyJson. I show it in a tableView and then when I tap a row, I open a link on the web.

But I have trouble parsing array.

```
array`[
    {
        "title": " ",
        "likes": 0,
        "post_id": 60050,
        "image": "",
        "image1": "",
        "image2": "",
        "data": "",
        "arguments": [
            "link",
            "url"
        ],
        "provider": "custom",
        "price": " usd",
        "desc": "",
        "shop": ""
    },`
```

My request:

```
Alamofire.request("").responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
    if ((response.result.value) != nil) {
        let swifts = JSON(response.result.value!)

        if let resData = swifts.arrayObject{
        }
        self.dataTable = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
    }
```

This to show text:

```
cell.titleLabel.text = indexData["arguments "] as? String
```

But when loaded, I have the error:

```
Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x600000228cc0>( url
```

Comment: It is dict in array.

Comment: and what I need do?

Comment: I am not properly cleared what actually you tring to do. Better if you re-write your json and some code where you wanted to show. it helps me to understand .

Comment: I tried parse "arguments" - to tableView and show it and move between views

Comment: Can you show me proper structure of your Json so that i can help you.

Comment: Yes. [
    {
        "title": "Комплект  ",
        "likes": 0,
        "post_id": 60050,
        "image": "https://pp.userapi.com/c7003/v7003337/49cca/-7atfdqbgxo.jpg",
        "image1": "https://pp.userapi.com/c7006/v7006036/3eac6/-hR9OAreyD8.jpg",
        "image2": "https://pp.userapi.com/c7006/v7006036/3eac6/-hR9OAreyD8.jpg",
        "data": "27.03.2018",
        "arguments": [
            "https://....",
            "url"
        ],

Comment: [Here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=0b9d13c66b6a4a10aa18a6056daa2626) is the response thats how API response looked like. Data is the same look like as your above response. If you could not show me response like this then I unable to help. BTW for security purpose you can change the values but not the format.

Comment: [link] ( https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=0fe867bf2b5444e58686726c963c71a3) _italic_ **bold** @dahiya_boy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am assuming you perfectly getting response from API. Now parse data like this.

1. Create a global variable `var arrData : [Any] = []`
2. Now call the api & get data like this.

   ```
   if ((response.result.value) != nil) {
       self.arrData = (response.result.value) // here your all response in arrData. 
       self.tblView.reloadData() // reload tableview
   }
   else{
       // you didn't get the data
   }
   ```
3. Now in TableView `DataSource`

   - In `numberOfRowsInSection`

     ```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrData.count 
     }
     ```
   - In `cellForRow`

     ```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "your_cell_id") as! YourCell

         let aDictValue = arrData[indexPath.row] as? [String : Any]

         cell.labelTitle.text = aDictValue["title"] as! String
         cell.labelProvider.text = aDictValue["provider"] as! String

         // set your data like this.

         return cell
     }
     ```

If still any issue then you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse it like that

```
let array = swifts["arguments"].arrayValue 

for item in array 
{
    print(item)

}
```